# How should a WebAPI method return an error response?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to see the error message in the Web API response. How should the exception message be shown in the response.

> Error CS0155  The type caught or thrown must be derived from
>   System.Exception

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllData()
{
    using (sandminingEntities entities = new sandminingEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok( entities.GPSTrackers.OrderByDescending(x=>x.DeviceTimeStamp).ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is that you throw a `System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' from your action method with an appropriate HTTP status code.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(exception.Message),
        ReasonPhrase = "Bad Request"
    };

    throw new HttpResponseException(message);
}

return result;
```

Comment: getting error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'

Comment: Modified the answer. The Content property is now an instance of StringContent.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need EX.MESSAGE
try it:

```
   catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex ;
                }
```